# Sequences in R with changing increments

Tags: r

How would I create an R sequence that returns

```
1, 4, 9, 16, 25, . . . , 100
```

I have tried

```
seq(from=1,to=100,by=(seq(from=3,to=100,by=2)))
```

but this gives me the completely wrong answer

Also, to get:

```
 1, −2, 3, 4, −5, 6, 7, −8, . . . , −98, 99, 100
```

would I use a true false vector?

Comment: Try this for second sequence `(1:100)*rep(c(1,-1,1),40)[1:100]`

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
v <- (1:10)^2
#  [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

All of the mathematical operations are vectorized in R, so just square the vector and you're good to go.

Comment: The second sequence: `(1:100)*-1^(1:100)`.

Comment: My answer may be too good but it can work `(1:100)*rep(c(1,-1,1),40)[1:100]`

Comment: @Sangram `seq.int(100)*c(1,-1,1)` is enough, the `c(1,-1,1)` is recycled

Answer (score 0):

For the second sequence the `rep` function will be helpful. The code

```
  rep(c(1,-1,1),33)*(1:99)
```

generates the required sequence from 1 to 99.

Comment: It's just math: `(1:100)*(-1)^(1:2)`  it throws a warning, but all it means is that `(1:2)` is being recycled.  If preferred: `x<-1:100` then `x*(-1)^x`.

Comment: `^(1:2)` causes a pos-neg-pos-neg-... sequence and not pos-neg-pos-pos-neg-... Do you mean `(1:100)*(-1)^(0:2)`? That generates the same sequence with a warning. And `c((1:99)*(-1)^(0:2),100)` is a variant without warning. Anyway, using the `rep` function is more intuitive here, I would say.